# how to get value from def function before

Tags: python, tkinter

i got a problem to run the python, for example code in below, because the code not sure to see because i am beginner for this,and its too long too, i give the same problem on my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.title('app')

class calculate:
     def thefirst(self):
         y1 = 1

     def second(self):
         v1 = 5 - y1
         print(v1)

Button(root, text="GENERATE", command=second)
```

the problem is if i press the button for y1 not define

so i writte the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.title('app')

class calculate:
     def thefirst(self):
         y1 = 1

     def second(self):
         for y1 from the first()
         v1 = 5 - y1
         print(v1)

Button(root, text="GENERATE", command=second)
```

but in my visual studio code got a red color problem, but the code is still not working to generate data, is my code wrong?

thank you

Comment: You should be getting a `NameError` on `second`, because it's class attribute, not a variable.

Comment: @chepner is correct. This should not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems on your code:

1. First of all, you need to define a constructor for your class `__init__` to assign the default value to your attributes.
2. You have to use `self.` for class attributes, otherwhise, the value will not be saved.
3. You need to instantiate the class, because you have to reference the instance function, no the class function, because is not static.

   ```
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import ttk

   root = Tk()

   root.title('app')

   class calculate:
       def __init__(self):
           self.y1 = 1

       def second(self):
           v1 = 5 - self.y1
           print(v1)

   calc = calculate()
   Button(root, text="GENERATE", command=calc.second)
   ```

I recommend you to search on internet about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) on Python, and learn the basics.

Comment: thank you somuch, for the solution and the suggestion, i want use this class before, but i am not understand because i dont have any suggestion to learn self. last question for the program, if i want to calling function of __init__ for the command from your example, is cal.__init__?? or i must set the new definition? thanks

Comment: @AnandaJulianNugraha, the ```__init__``` is called when the object is created, in this case in the line ```calc = calculate()```, if you want to set self.y1 to one in other parts of the program, you can create a function like the function ```thefirst``` in your question, but changing ```y1 = 1``` to ```self.y1 = 1```

Comment: so its like duplicate the function `__init__` and create a new one with function name `thefirst` ? @RodrigoLlanes

Comment: @AnandaJulianNugraha, yes